# complex sql query counting and grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

in table `LOG` i have the following entries

```
userid     item     role
1          Apple    Buyer
2          Banana   Seller
3          Apple    Buyer
1          Banana   Seller
3          Orange   Buyer
etc
```

i'm trying to create the following two tables with SQL. table 1:

```
 item      countUser1Buy      countUser1Sell
 Apple
 Banana
 Orange
```

AND TAble 2 (here i mean the mean of totals. as in, the mean of the total apples bought

```
 item      alluserBuyTotalMean      allUserBuyTotalMedian   allUserBuyRange   allUserBuyStandardDev
 Apple
 Banana
 Orange
```

i think the first should be a variation on

```
`SELECT `item`, `role`, count(`item`) as count FROM `LOG` GROUP BY `item`
```

which is close, giving me

```
item    role   count
Apple   Buyer   1
Banana  Seller  1
```

but i cant figure out how to make it as i'm trying to get. the second i'm really stumped. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query:

```
SELECT item
     , SUM(role = 'Buyer') AS countUser1Buy
     , SUM(role = 'Seller') AS countUser1Sell
  FROM LOG
 WHERE userid = 1
 GROUP BY item;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT item
     , AVG(total) AS alluserBuyTotalMean
     , CONCAT(MIN(total), ' - ', MAX(total)) AS allUserBuyRange
     , STDDEV_POP(total) AS allUserBuyStandardDev
  FROM (
       SELECT item
            , COUNT(*) AS total
         FROM LOG
        WHERE role = 'Buyer'
        GROUP BY item, userid
       ) t
 GROUP BY item;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
SELECT `item`, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN role='Seller' THEN 1 END) AS countUserSell,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN role='Buyer' THEN 1 END) AS countUserBuy  
FROM `LOG` 
GROUP BY `item`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
`item`
,SUM(CASE WHEN `userid`= 1 AND `role` = 'Buyer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as countUser1Buy
,SUM(CASE WHEN `userid` = 1 AND `role` = 'Seller' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as countUser1Sell
FROM `LOG`
GROUP BY Item
```

You will need to make a new `CASE` statement for each userid, but this should work.  Results in the following:

```
item    countUser1Buy   countUser1Sell
Apple   1               0
Banana  0               1
Orange  0               0
```